# Apache Ant is creating bizarre directories

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am defining a new buildfile and (for reasons outside the scope of this question) I need to place it inside `projectRoot/build`, as opposed to the normal `projectRoot`:

```
MyProject
    src/
        <Java source>
    build/
        build.xml
        build.properties
```

So inside `build.xml`:

```
<project name="myproject-build" basedir="..">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <target name="mkdirs">
        <mkdir dir="${gen.dir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

And inside `build.properties`:

```
gen.dir=generated
```

So, if I run `mkdirs` from the command-line, you would *expect* it to produce the following directory structure:

```
MyProject
    src/
        <Java source>
    generated/
    build/
        build.xml
        build.properties
```

But instead, I am getting:

```
MyProject
    src/
        <Java source>
    ${gen.dir}
    build/
        build.xml
        build.properties
```

What's going on? Why won't Ant properly import the `build.properties` file? Or is something else going on? I suspect it has something to do with `basedir`, but I can't change the fact that the build *has* to exist inside `build/build.xml`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Setting `basedir` changes where it's looking for the `build.properties` file. Change your import to this:

```
<property file="build/build.properties"/>
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`property file="build/build.properties"/>` should fix it

Need 30 character here.. damm